# Get ndim of pybind11 list

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

How can I get the n dimension of a pybind11 list? I'm trying to find something like this:

```
py::list lists = source; 
if ((*source[1]).cast<py::list>().ndim() == 1){
    throw std::runtime_error("source should be 2-D"); 
}
```

And my lists looks like this:

```
lists = [array([[2,3,4,4],[2,3,3,3]]), array([0,1])]
```

Unfortunately ndim() doesn't exist for pybind11 list. What else can I use to find ndim() of array([0,1])?

Comment: I doubt that a Python list can have dimensions - it's 1 dimension (like to expect for a list). My guess: You have to retrieve the items of the list which are arrays in your case. Then, you can retrieve the `ndim` of the arrays. (I didn't find a member function `ndim()` but I'm no expert. What I found is: The `py::buffer_info` can be requested from an `py::array_t`. Then the `ndim` is a member _variable_ of the `py::buffer_info`. [NumPy - Vectorizing functions](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/pycpp/numpy.html#vectorizing-functions) - the source code sample looks promising.)

Comment: Is it possible to convert a py::list to a py::array_t?

Comment: Actually I can! I referenced my array_t like this and it works : `py::array_t<double> test = (*source[1]).cast<py::list>();`. After I can just call test.ndim() and I get the good dimensions!